# Swift dilema(The titles are difficult to come up with)

Tags: swift

I just started learning Swift a couple days ago and I've run into this problem when following a tutorial.
 [I tried to add the code in text but was having formatting problems so I had to go with an image of the code:(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayje0.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

this is the corrected code. 
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var currentValue: Int = 0
var targetValue: Int = 0
func startNewRound() {
    targetValue = 1 + Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    currentValue = 50
    slider.value = Float(currentValue) }

func updateLabels() {
        targetLabel.text = "\(targetValue)"
     }


@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var targetLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startNewRound()
    updateLabels()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a       nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func showAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello World",
        message: "The value of the slider is \(currentValue)"
        + "\nThe target value is: \(targetValue)",

        preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default,
                               handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)

    present(alert, animated:true , completion: nil)
    startNewRound()
    updateLabels()
}
@IBAction func sliderMOved(slider: UISlider) {
    currentValue = lroundf(slider.value) }

}
```

Comment: Your "startNewRound" method has no closing `}` and the following "updateLabels" is inside "startNewRound". Pay attention to how you indent your code and this won't happen.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code, if there are any formatting problems that you don't know how to fix yet, other people can edit your question to help you. By the way, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks! it was a bracket issue

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method `updateLabels()` in your `ViewController` class. Take a look:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func startNewRound() {
        targetValue = 1
    func updateLabels() {
        targetLabel.text = "\(targetValue)" } // <- see?
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateLabels()
    }
}
```

You probably didn't see it, but see how it looks when we fix your code's formatting:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func startNewRound() {
        targetValue = 1
        func updateLabels() {
            targetLabel.text = "\(targetValue)"
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateLabels()
    }
}
```

Did you see it now? There is a local function named `updateLabels()` inside of the `startNewRound()` method, but the compiler is right to complain that there is an unresolved identifier there.

Comment: Add the code to your question anyway. This question will remain here on StackOverflow for years to come. It's good etiquette to make it self contained in case someone wants to read it.

Comment: You're right, but I just wanted to teach the new guy some manners ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo

```
func startNewRound() {
    // Some stuff
    func updateLabels() {
       // Some stuff
}
```

You should have

```
func startNewRounds() {
   // Some stuff
}
func updateLabels() {
    // Some Stuff
}
```

Comment: I know. I was just telling you that you wrote your `updateLabels` function inside you `startNewRound`. That's why you have the error `Use of unresolved identifier`.